# I am looking for a formula that counts the number of rows between cells with a number 1 in

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2021

I have the following table:

[image]

I have the following formula in column `B4`

```
=IF(A4="","",MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(A5:A1872),,),0))
```

The formula is counting the number of blank rows between the number 1 in column A.

The formula i want though is one that puts my numbers like in `Column C` ie a step down. The 4 in `B12` should be in `B16`. The 2 in `B16` should be in `B18` an so on.

Can someone help. I have **Excel 2021**?

I do not have the `DROP()` function in **Excel 2021**

Comment: Do you expect a value in `B4`?

Comment: no i wouldn't expect a value in B4 as there is nothing above it

Comment: are you counting the number of blank lines in between plus 1?, on row 24 for example I was expecting 5 instead of 6. Thanks

Comment: I am also counting the number 1 above it. Sorry i should have been clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the first answer provided by @DavidLeal, though simplifying things somewhat:

```
=LET(
    ζ,A1:A12,
    ξ,ROW(ζ),
    IF(ζ=1,1+DROP(FREQUENCY(IF(ζ="",ξ),IF(ζ<>"",ξ,0)),-1),"")
)
```

Comment: Hello Jos, i am not familiar with Let formulas can you explain how your answer works?

Comment: I get a #NAME? error when trying to implement this

Comment: @Ingram a quick search in the google lets you know why you are getting **[#NAME?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-name-error-b6d54e31-a743-4d7d-9b61-40002a7b4286)** error. assuming you may not be using `MS365` so you are getting the error or it could be there is a `typo` there are other possible reasons.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya i dont have M365 I have excel 2021. I have just been reading up about the drop function and it is only available on M365. Can i have a solution for M2021

Comment: This is the alternative you could try which will work with your version of `Excel` not changing the original formula posted by @Jos Woolley Sir except the `DROP()` --> `=LET(
    ζ,A1:A12,
    ξ,ROW(ζ),
    IF(A1:A12=1,1+INDEX(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A12="",ROW(A1:A12)),IF(A1:A12<>"",ROW(A1:A12),0)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(ζ))),"")
)`

Comment: @Ingram use `INDEX()` & `SEQUENCE()` instead of `DROP()`

Comment: @Ingram LET is used to avoid repetition of the same calculation. We assume here if you don't add specific tag with the version, there is no Excel version constraints. You need to replace all the variables in the IF statement to remove the LET, for example: `=IF(A1:A12=1,1+DROP(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A12="",ROW(A1:A12)),IF(A1:A12<>"",ROW(A1:A12),0)),-1),"")`

Comment: true @MayukhBhattacharya he needs to replace DROP too

Comment: @Ingram here is the updated formula from Mayukh: `=IF(A1:A12=1,1+INDEX(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A12="",ROW(A1:A12)),IF(A1:A12<>"",ROW(A1:A12),0)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:A12))),"")` I tested and it works. If you don't have `SEQUENCE` then it would be more complicated

Comment: @David Leal If i didn't have sequence what would the formula be?

Comment: @ Mayukh Bhattacharya What would the formula be if i did not have sequence?

Comment: @Ingram for this case you can replace it with `ROW` as follows: `=IF(A1:A12=1,1+INDEX(FREQUENCY(IF(A1:A12="",ROW(A1:A12)),IF(A1:A12<>"",ROW(A1:A12),0)),ROW(A1:A12)),"")` since you started on row one, if that is not the case,  and you started on row `4` for example, then replace the last call of  `ROW(A1:A12)` with: `ROW(A4:A12)-ROW(A4)+1`

Comment: Hey @ Ingram sorry didn't got the notification, as you missed out proper tagging. anyways you already have resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
=LET(a,A4:A1872,
     b,ROW(a)*a,
     m,MMULT(--(TOROW(b)<b)*(TOROW(b)<>0),SEQUENCE(ROWS(b),,1,0)),
     x,TOCOL(IF(ISERR(1/b),NA(),b),3),
IF(b,b-INDEX(x,m),""))
```

This extracts the row number of the previous found value from the current row.
)That means that the first value would show 0.)

Comment: I was testing it, and If found certain scenarios where it doesn't work. For example if the empty string is a result of a formula, for example: `=""` returns `#VALUE!`, so maybe that would be an assumption. If the first `1` is not in the first position of the range, it provides a wrong result for the first `1`, returning `0`. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I provided a formula purely on the info provided. Jos' version is winning though!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are counting the number of blank lines plus one, as it is in the sample. The following works regardless of the starting value, it could be `1` or  blank. It also works if the blank cell is created by a formula, for example: `=""`. This answer assumes *there is no Excel version constraints as per the tags listed in the question* (*formula 1*).

```
=LET(A, A1:A15, seq, SEQUENCE(ROWS(A)),
 freq, DROP(FREQUENCY(IF(A="",seq), IF(A<>"",seq)),-1),
 f,FILTER(seq,A<>""), MAP(seq,LAMBDA(s,XLOOKUP(s,f,freq+1,""))))
```

Here another way using `SCAN` to count blanks within each group, then call  `MAP` to find the max count per group, i.e. where the count (`c`) is zero take the previous element. Treating the case when the first `1` is at the beginning, in such situation `INDEX(c,-1)` produces an error, so `IFERROR` returns `1` (*formula 2*):

```
=LET(A,A1:A15, seq,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A)), c,SCAN(0,A,LAMBDA(ac,x,IF(x="",ac+1,0))),
 MAP(seq,LAMBDA(s,IF(INDEX(c,s,1)=0,IFERROR(INDEX(c,IF(s=1,0,s)-1)+1,1),""))))
```

Here is the output for *formula 1*:
[image]

The main idea in *formula 1* is using `FREQUENCY` to do the counts. Idea taken from here: [Occurrence in an excel serie](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/occurrence-in-an-excel-serie/m-p/3807794), answer from @JosWoolley and credit to him. We remove the last value of `freq`, since it is the last bin (open interval). We are going to have as many frequency values as `1`'s are in the input. Now using `MAP` over the index positions (`seq`) and using `XLOOKUP` to find the specific index positions (`f`, index positions of the `1`'s ) and to return the corresponding frequency (`freq`) plus `1`. If the index position was not found, then it means it is a blank row, so we return an empty string.

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating a bit; `FREQUENCY` is sufficient on its own if you coerce an appropriate *bins_array*: `=LET(ζ,A1:A12,ξ,ROW(ζ),IF(ζ=1,1+DROP(FREQUENCY(IF(ζ="",ξ),IF(ζ<>"",ξ,0)),-1),""))`

Comment: Amazing @JosWoolley. Please feel free to post your own answer, it is a significant improvement from mine. If you prefer to leave it as a comment, then I will update my answer giving you credit for the improvement. Thanks